# How do you call a function on data in the template of AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Right now I am trying to figure out how to create an anchor element automatically for some data in a template, and I am basically calling this:
`{{linkify(section.uri)}}`.

- I know that is wrong, but what is the right way to do this?
- Also, what sort of terminology should I be using to describe this problem?

Comment: problem really isn't clear. To create a whole element you use a directive...not sure what objective is here or what `linkify()` does. Show all relevant code and explain issue in proper detail

Answer (score 2):

create an html anchor element and use angular `ng-href` to set the url with a JS value

```
<a ng-href="{{section.url}}">link</a>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref